# I want to obtain a certain part of text from a large webpage using Javascript, how do I?

Tags: javascript

There is a certain webpage which randomly generates a number, for example `"Frequency : 21"`. I am trying to create a script which takes the number, `21`, and compares it to another variable, then to an `if else` function. Basically, I've completed most of it, but I can't obtain the number `21`. And since it is random, I can't put in a fixed value.
Can anyone help me out?

My code goes like:

```
setTimeout(MyFunction,5000)

function MyFunction(level,legmin) {
  var level = x
  var legmin = 49
  if (level <= legmin) {
    location.reload(true)
  }
  else {
    alert("Met requirements.")
  }
```

where the address of the text I want is:

```
html>body>div#container>div#contentContainer>div#content>
div#scroll>div#scrollContent>div>div>div#pkmnappear>form>p (x in the code above).
```

Comment: You provided a selector in your question. JavaScript has `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, which use CSS-style selectors to select elements. So... `var level = Number(document.querySelector("div#pkmnappear>form>p").textContent)`

Comment: If the word `Frequency :` is in there, then use basic string methods to remove it before converting it to a `Number`.

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick-n-dirty solution without regex.

```
var lookFor = "Frequency : ";
var text = document.querySelector("#pkmnappear>form>p").textContent;
var level = text.substr(text.indexOf(lookFor) + lookFor.length).split(" ")[0];
```

This assumes the number will be followed by a space

Comment: Thanks. If we were to complicate the situation further, like the webpage could either generate a value or display some text. Even the value is random. In this case, if I wanted to reload until I got a value that was greater than 50, how would I go about doing so? I tried to, but got stuck on the text part. (The text part is under div>div>div#pkmnappear)

Comment: @ParthMane : To check if `level` in my code is a number greater than 50 you would do `var levelNum = Number(level); var isGreaterThan50 = (Number.isFinite(levelNum) && levelNum > 50)`. I don't understand what you meant about reloading, so please explain further if you need more help.

Comment: The reloading part is to reload the page until a desired frequency is obtained. That part is easy, else { reload(true) }